# Apollo useLazyQuery "onCompleted" callback getting fired twice

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Here is my code:

```
const [getComputers] = useLazyQuery(GET_COMPUTERS, {
fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
onCompleted: (data) => {
  console.log('called') //this is called twice
  if (data && data.details && data.details.color === 'blue') {
    releaseColor(mutationArgs)
  } else {
    //setError('Unit is not on Hold.')
  }
},
})

 const handleClick = () => {
 setLoading(true)
    getComputers()
  }
```

**The problem**

The onCompleted callback is fired twice for some reason in this. I tried setting the different fetch policies and also the deduplication flag to false but for weird reason, it is always fired twice! Any thoughts?